# Read 2 files in C to calculate Manhattan Distance

Tags: c, file

I need some help just starting off my code for this program. This is my first time reading a file in c and I have been stuck starting it off. Essentially, I need to read in two files to calculate Manhattan Distance and output the ID for each file and the closest distance. The files look something like this:

```
3,2
0, 3.4, 4.3
1, 4.5, 6.1
2, 7.2, 3.9
```

```
3,2
0, 5.9, 6.7
1, 8.5, 1.2
2, 9.8, 4.9
```

My current code only outputs the table and I am trying to find a way to use columns as a way to calculate Manhattan distance. The 3,2 signifies the rows and columns and the 0,1,2 are the IDs. Here is the current code I have found online and modified a bit that I thought may be useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  
    FILE* testFile = fopen("Test.txt", "r");

    if (!testFile)
        printf("Can't open file\n");

    else {
        char buffer[1024];

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        while (fgets(buffer, 1024, testFile)) {
            column = 0;
            row++;

            if (row == 1)
                continue;

            // Splitting the data
            char* value = strtok(buffer, ", ");

            while (value) {
                // Column 1
                if (column == 0) {
                    printf("TestID:");
                }

                // Column 2
                if (column == 1) {
                    printf("\tx1: ");
                }

                // Column 3
                if (column == 2) {
                    printf("\ty1: ");
                }

                printf("%s", value);
                value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
                column++;
            }

            printf("\n");
        }

        // Close the file
        fclose(testFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So now try opening two files at the same time. And you already split each line into tokens, you can convert strings to integers using [`atoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi).

Comment: "Can't open file" is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Replace `printf("Can't open file\n");` with `perror("Test.txt");`.  It will write the error message to the correct stream and include the reason for the `fopen` error.

Comment: Dont use `strtok`.  Parse the line first with `strtoul` to validate the row number, then use `strtod` to read the doubles.

Comment: @WilliamPursell how do I go about adding the stroul and strtok? I am not at all familiar with those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example demonstrating one method of parsing your input files with `strtod` and `strtoul`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mat {
    int rows;
    int columns;
    double *data;
};

void
show(const struct mat *A)
{
    double *d = A->data;
    for( int i = 0; i < A->rows; i += 1 ){
        for( int j = 0; j < A->columns; j += 1 ){
            printf("%f\t", *d++);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

/*
 * Return nonzero if the first non-whitespace
 * character after *e is not v.  Terminate search
 * at a newline.
 */
int
expect_next(char **e, const char v)
{
    char *end = *e;
    while( isspace(*end) && *end != '\n' ){
        end += 1;
    }
    *e = end + 1;
    return *end != v;
}

int
get_data(struct mat *A, const char *path)
{
    unsigned line = 1;
    FILE* testFile = fopen(path, "r");
    if( testFile == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        return 0;
    }
    char buffer[1024];
    char *end = buffer;

    if( fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, testFile) == NULL ){
        if( ferror(testFile) ){
            perror(path);
        } else {
            goto bad_input;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    A->rows = strtoul(buffer, &end, 10);
    if( expect_next(&end, ',') ){
        goto bad_input;
    }
    A->columns = strtoul(end, &end, 10);
    if( expect_next(&end, '\n') ){
        goto bad_input;
    }
    A->data = malloc(A->rows * A->columns * sizeof *A->data);
    if( A->data == NULL ){
        perror("malloc");
        return 0;
    }
    double *val = A->data;

    unsigned row = 0;
    while( NULL != fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, testFile) ){
        line += 1;
        unsigned v = strtoul(buffer, &end, 10);
        if( v != row ){
            goto bad_input;
        }
        if( expect_next(&end, ',') ){
            goto bad_input;
        }
        unsigned col = 0;
        while( col < A->columns && *end ){
            *val++ = strtod(end, &end);
            if( expect_next(&end, ++col == A->columns ? '\n' : ',') ){
                goto bad_input;
            }
        }
        if( col != A->columns ){
            goto bad_input;
        }
        row += 1;
    }
    if( row != A->rows ){
        goto bad_input;
    }

    if( fclose(testFile) ){
        perror(path);
    }
    return 1;
bad_input:
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid input at line %u, column %u\n", path,
        line, (unsigned)(end - buffer));
    return 0;
}


int
main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char *args[] = { NULL, "/dev/stdin", NULL };
    if( argc < 2 ){
        argv = args;
    }
    for( argv += 1; *argv; argv += 1 ){
        struct mat A;
        if( get_data(&A, *argv) ){
            show(&A);
        }
    }
}
```